# Add column with percentage of matching words in two different columns (by row) in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a tbl_df and want to see the percentage of matching words between two strings.

The data looks like this:

```
# A tibble 3 x 2
       X                 Y
     <chr>             <chr>
1 "mary smith"      "mary smith"
2 "mary smith"      "john smith"
3 "mike williams"   "jack johnson"
```

Desired output (% by row, in any order):

```
# A tibble 3 x 3 
       X               Y           Z 
     <chr>           <chr>        <dbl>
1 "mary smith"    "mary smith"     1.0 
2 "mary smith"    "john smith"     0.50 
3 "mike williams" "jack johnson"   0.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to check for the `length` of common words (`intesect`) after `split`ting the column by space and divide the `length`

```
df1$Z <- mapply(function(x, y)  length(intersect(x, y))/length(x), 
            strsplit(df1$X, " "), strsplit(df1$Y, " "))
df$Z
#[1] 1.0 0.5 0.0
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`, we can use `map2` and apply the same logic

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Z = map2(strsplit(X, " "), strsplit(Y, " "), ~ 
                       length(intersect(.x, .y))/length(.x)))
 #             X            Y   Z
#1    mary smith   mary smith   1
#2    mary smith   john smith 0.5
#3 mike williams jack johnson   0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = c("mary smith", "mary smith", "mike williams"
), Y = c("mary smith", "john smith", "jack johnson")), .Names = c("X", 
"Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: The base R approached worked. It was able to still match words even if they were in a different order in the Y column. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` option using `stringr::str_split`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(Z = map2(str_split(X, " "), str_split(Y, " "), ~sum(.x == .y) / length(.x)))
#              X            Y   Z
#1    mary smith   mary smith   1
#2    mary smith   john smith 0.5
#3 mike williams jack johnson   0
```

or using `stringi::stri_extract_all_words`

```
library(stringi)
df %>%
    mutate(Z = map2(stri_extract_all_words(X), stri_extract_all_words(Y), ~sum(.x == .y) / length(.x)))
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    '       X                 Y
 "mary smith"      "mary smith"
 "mary smith"      "john smith"
 "mike williams"   "jack johnson"', header = T)
```

Comment: I like the tidyverse approach, but it is appears not to catch if the words are in a different order in the Y column. Is there a way to reorder the words first in each column so they are alphabetical? Word order in not important in my final output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `stringsim()` in `stringdist` package:

```
library(stringdist)

tbl <- tibble(x = c("mary smith", "mary smith", "mike williams"),
              y = c("mary smith", "john smith", "jack johnson"))

# lv = levenshtein distance
tbl %>% mutate(z = stringsim(x, y, method ='lv'))

# jw =  jaro-winkler 
tbl %>% mutate(z = stringsim(x, y, method ='jw'))

## > tbl %>% mutate(z = stringsim(x, y, method ='lv'))
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##  x             y                 z
##  <chr>         <chr>         <dbl>
## 1 mary smith    mary smith   1.00  
## 2 mary smith    john smith   0.600 
## 3 mike williams jack johnson 0.0769

## > tbl %>% mutate(z = stringsim(x, y, method ='jw'))
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   x             y                z
##  <chr>         <chr>        <dbl>
## 1 mary smith    mary smith   1.00 
## 2 mary smith    john smith   0.733
## 3 mike williams jack johnson 0.494
```

Comment: This calculates the edit distance in terms of characters, not words.

Comment: I think there's a merit to using the charter based approach based on my experience. There are lots of variations/error/typos in real data. Word based approach will yield ~0.5 when 'john smith' and 'johnn smith'

Comment: I will actually use the distance methods as a second layer for my matching needs. Thanks!